# email validation accept two dot just in the form

Tags: javascript, html

my problem is I want The email should have no spaces in it and the domain name should be either two words separated by a ‘.’ or three words separated by two dots e.g. username@abc.efg.xy.
and not acceptable to more than three dot

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"  >
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name">
    <br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="femail" placeholder="saleh@gmail.com">
    <br>
    Message: <input class="filed" type="text" size="60" style="height:200px">
    <br>
    Age : <input type="text" name="fage" placeholder="between 10 and 120">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>


<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["femail"].value;
    var z = document.forms["myForm"]["fage"].value;

    if (x == "" || x == null || y == "" || z == null) {
        alert("You must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(z) || z < 10 || z > 120) {
        alert("the age should be between 10 and 120 ");
        return false;

    }

    if (!y.includes('@') ) { // i do not how to complete the if condition 
        alert("The emali not include @ or more one . ");
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your're in for a ride

You can use a regular expression to test if the input is an email, NOTE the following answer tests true to 99.9% of the email addresses, but could still fail

```
const emailReg = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.){1,2}[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)

if (emailReg.test(y)){
    //do something if the email is indeed an email
}
```

I added some examples in a regex validator https://regex101.com/r/vJ7A3N/1/

source: https://emailregex.com/

you could also use `<input type="email" id="email" name="email">`

Comment: Unfortunately not work i do if (! emailReg.test(y)){ alert("The emali  is valid");
                 return false; }

Comment: sorry my bad should work now, i had quotes where they should not have been!

Comment: is work but there something strang if I put one dot like this "ss@gmail.com" is not work  and if I put more than one dot is work and this I do want I want is acceptable just one or two-dot I hope my question is clear

Comment: strange in my test env, i tested ss@gmail.com and it validated as an email

Comment: oh sorry for that yes is work but also is acceptable more than two-dot like that "ss@sss.edu.us.ss how can make this not acceptable sorry for a lot of comments

Comment: @samxxsam edited the regex to your liking! https://regex101.com/r/Tnn87d/1/ make sure to mark the answer if it worked!